# What's wrong with this jQuery .get statement syntax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to debug this simple .get request using jQuery.  For some reason, the alert is not firing:

```
$.get("/count", { room_key: roomKey, groom_id: groomId, user_id: userId }, function(data) {
    alert('Load was performed.');
    });
```

When I view the request in Firebug and in my server log, everything works as expected...except for firing the alert (ie., the server responds with the expected information - it's an array of JSON data.)

EDIT1

I distilled the issue...the response is an composed of two arrays of JSON data that looks like this:

```
[{"total"=>0}][{"room"=>"room name"}]
```

When I remove either the first array or the 2nd array, the callback fires.

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Add an error handler, if you aren't getting the success handler, the error handler is getting called. `.fail(function(){console.log(arguments)})`

Comment: Replace 'function(data)' with 'function(data,response)' and provide log/alert of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json must be valid, otherwise jQuery will respond with a "parseerror" message.

http://jsonlint.com

```
[{"total":0},{"room":"room name"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone!  I figured my JSON was invalid.  Now just have to figure out how to get the valid syntax I need out of my models/rack.